# Why it's failed to install angular/cdk?

Tags: angular, github, npm-install, angular-cdk

I'm new to Angular2. I'm trying to perform this command:
 - npm install --save angular/cdk

for some reason it asked me for a user name and password. Not sure if that's the system user/pwd or Github's one. Anyway I entered if wrong. Now then I try to execute same command it doesn't ask for user/pwd but throws an error:

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\USR_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror
git@github.com:angular/cdk.git C:\Users\USR_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-angular-cdk-git-xxxxxxxxxxxx....
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\USR_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-angular-cdk-git-xxxxxxxxxxxx'...
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

So how do I reset or install it properly?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you on windows, linux or mac?

Comment: Use `@angular/cdk` and not just `angular/cdk`.

Comment: I'm on Windows and @angular/cdk does work.. Thanks everybody